# Check if list contains another list. C#

Tags: c#, .net

EDIT, just saying the comment in the ContainsAllItem explains best.

Im sorry for asking, I know this was asked before, but I just did not get it.
Ok, so I want to check If a list contains all the items in another list *WITHOUT* overlapping, aswell as compare the items based on the classes string, name variable(called itemname and it is public).

```
public class Item
{
    public string itemname;
}
```

So basically, have a class(lets say.. class A) with a list of items, and a function that checks takes the list of items of class A, and then compares it to another list(lets call it B), but compare it by the itemname variable not the whole item.

And most importantly could you explain in detail what it does.

So how the function/class would look as of now.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public List<Item> myItems = new List<Item>();

    public bool ContainsAllItems(List<Item> B)
    {
        //Make a function that compares the to lists by itemname and only returns true if the myItems list contains ALL, items in list b.
        //Also could you explain how it works.
    }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And by *without overlapping* you mean the list should be equal?

Answer (score 12):

I haven't checked the pref on this, but linq does have the Except operator.

```
 var x = new int[] {4,5};
 var y = new int[] {1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5};   

 y.Except(x).Any(); //true, not all items from y are in x
 x.Except(y).Any(); // false, all items from x are in y
```

Answer (score 9):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but performance wise you should definitely use [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`IsProperSubsetOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It can do what you want in orders of magnitude less time:

```
HashSet<string> a = new HashSet<string>(list1.Select(x => x.itemname));
HashSet<string> b = new HashSet<string>(list2.Select(x => x.itemname));

a.IsProperSubsetOf(b)
```

**Explanation:** `HashSet` uses the item's `GetHashCode` value and `Equals` method in an efficient way to compare items. That means that when it internally goes through the values in `b` it doesn't have to compare it to all other items in a. It uses the hash code (and an internal hash function) to check whether it already has that value or doesn't.

Because it does only a single check for every item (each check is O(1)) it's much faster than checking **all** items in `a` which would take O(n) (for each item in `b` that is).

Comment: Also where do you learn these things? Any good tutorials, MDSN, or college?

Comment: @user3210251 Yes. MSDN, StackOverflow, experience, other team members, less tutorials for me, and even less from college.

Comment: @user3210251 `=>` is a part of a lambda expression. You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
B.All(itB=>myItems.Select(itA=>itA.ItemName).Contains(itB.ItemName))
```

Will run in O(N^2) time, but it's cool you can do that in just one rather unreadable line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way.  I included a way to include and exclude the list comparison.

```
var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var b = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

//Exists in list a but not in b
var c = (from i 
            in a 
         let found = b.Any(j => j == i) 
         where !found select i)
         .ToList();

//Exists in both lists
var d = (from i 
            in a  
         let found = b.Any(j => j == i) 
         where found select i)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: except() is what you want